# Trouble installing SwiftKey via APKPure

Tags: updates, safe-mode, swiftkey

I don't have a Google account and use APKPure (and F-Droid) to get most apps I need. Now, there are a few apps which, after download, refuse to install - they give me the "App not installed" error when I try to install them from within the APKPure interface. Right now I'm seeing this with the SwiftKey Keyboard application: I already use it, and I'm trying to install an upgrade of it but getting that error.

- How can I determine why I'm getting the "App not installed" message?
- Should I try installing in "Safe Mode"? I've heard about it but don't yet know how to get into it.
- If I want to try and install manually - where do I find the APK file(s) for my app?

Additional informations:

- I'm using a Xiaomi Redmi 3S with Android version 6.0.1.
- SwiftKey is already installed and is in use; but just to be sure, I replaced it with another keyboard as the chose/active keyboard app and the results are the same.
- The APK file *seems* to be [this one](https://apkpure.com/swiftkey-keyboard/com.touchtype.swiftkey/download?from=details) (assuming I get the same file from my desktop and from my APKPure app on my Android device).
- ```
  $ apksigner verify SwiftKey\ Keyboard_v6.6.9.32_apkpure.com.apk 
  WARNING: META-INF/DEPENDENCIES not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
  ```

Comment: Related: ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4226132/2533433) What Android version does your device run? Did you have the app (here: Swiftkey) installed before?

Comment: @Izzy: See edit.

Comment: Thanks! Next, could you check that Swiftkey APK: what's the minimum Android version required? If you have the chance running it via `apksigner verify swiftkey.apk`, could it be it is missing a v1 signature and has a v2 sig only (you should also be able to guess that by opening the APK with a ZIP manager and look into the `META-INF/` directory. If there's a v1 sig, there should be 2 cert files. If not, it cannot install on Android <7).

Comment: @Izzy: See edit. Does that fit your second option?

Comment: It indirectly answers that: As v2 protects the entire APK automatically, a single unprotected file being reported means there must be a v1 signature. OK, one case ruled out, the signature seems to be OK. Requirements on APKPure state "Android 4.1+", so the second possibility (the APK being for 7+ only) can be buried as well. One point still open: Was the app already installed on your device before? Also, could you check `logcat` while trying the install? That might give some further clues.

Comment: @Izzy: Already said that it was, but see edit. Also - what is logcat? (going to look that up.)

Comment: Then it might be that either it wasn't cleanly uninstalled before (happens sometimes: if e.g. the app's directory in `/data/data` remains, that might result in an UID mismatch on a later install, or signatures might collide if eg. one was installed from F-Droid and the other not). As for `logcat`, take a look at our [logging tag-wiki](/tags/logging/info).

Comment: @Izzy: Well, it was never uninstalled, i.e. I still use it after the installation fails. However, the initial installation came with the phone, so maybe that could be the reason.

Comment: The log should then reveal a signature mismatch. Or whatever is the reason if that's not the one.

Comment: @Izzy: Using CatLog, I'm told that I can't access other apps' log without root privileges - and I am hesitant to root my device (something I haven't done before). Do you think uninstalling and re-installing the newer version should work?

Comment: To the first part: use `adb logcat` (take a look at our [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info) if you haven't installed that yet; there are also links for minimal installations). To the second part: Maybe – depends on what the underlying issue is, so I'd first consult logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Izzy's patient advice in the comments, I got impatient and finally resolved this.

#### The reason for "App not installed" in OP's case

The pre-installed version of the SwiftKey Keyboard app had some sort of incompatibility with more recent versions - a "signature mismatch" - preventing an upgrade from the former to the latter.

#### Should I try installing in "Safe Mode"?

Not relevant in this case.

#### So how do I upgrade SwiftKey?

Uninstall SwiftKey (just the main package; there may be auxiliary packages) and install the new version.### How to determine why you get "App not installed" generally

It's tricky. What you can do is have a look at the "logs":

1. Install a log viewer app like CatLog
2. Install something like Termux (or an SSH server, then SSH into your phone)
3. In a terminal, run `adb logcat`
4. Try installing SwiftKey
5. Have a look at the what you get in the log

You need to redirect the log output into a text file if you can't scroll your terminal well enough.